# Orchard CMS - How to call a view (shape) from within a widget

Tags: razor, orchardcms

I'm building an Orchard child theme, and I've got a shape in theme's `Views` folder with a filename called `SocialButtons.cshtml`, the same format as the other views, eg branding.cshtml etc. I can place this using layout.cshtml using

> WorkContext.Layout.TripelSecond.Add(New.SocialButtons(), "5");

But when I do this, it plays around with the layout of 3 `div` tags that should be sitting side by side.

I know that I can put the HTML that is in my `SocialButtons` shape into a new HTML Widget, but for the purpose of this task, I don't want the HTML to be editable from within the admin (allowing it to be removed by unpublishing the widget is ok). What I want to know is if I can create an HTML widget which allows me to call the shape?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it either by adding a layout widget, then add shape element to it with ShapeType `SocialButtons`, or add new widget content type `SocialButtonsWidget`, and display your shape in it.

Comment: Brilliant...I was trying to use something from the dropdown on the shape element, didn't realise it was as simple as entering the shape name